# Detecting the position of a core plot graph

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, ipod

I am writing an iPhone/iPod app that uses core plot.  I want the user to scroll the graph and show the actual value (which I store an array) for that particular point on the graph.  I have figured out how to place a static line over the graph but have not found a way to detect what the position of the graph is.  Can someone point me in the right place?  Thanks!

Comment: Were you attempting to get the yValue of a plot at a particular xValue? Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean to do by detecting the position. But you can always use the `CPTPlotSpaceDelegate` methods and also the `CPTPlotSpace` method to understand more about what the user is doing with the graph.

Two specific methods come to mind:

```
- (CGPoint) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector
```

which gives you the amount by which the graph has been displaced, and also

```
- (void) plotPoint:(NSDecimal *) plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

which converts a CGPoint to a plot space coordinate.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This was helpful but not exactly what I am looking for.  I want to be able to know the exact point on the x-axis I am on at, say, the middle of the graph (that the user has scrolled to), so that I can look up the y value in my array.  This call gives me the number of points that the view has scrolled which might not work out perfectly. I suspect, however, that the delegate call you have given me many be the only way of doing it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For my graph this works fine.

```
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction  = YES;

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(temp-1.2) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(7.8)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-4.9) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50)];
```

where temp == smallest value of x-Axis data.